# Is there any equivalent method to `Find` with composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, interface, entity-framework-6

I want to know is there any equivalent method to `Find` with composite key.

For Example :

```
 public CITY Find(int id)
  { 
    return context.CITies.Find(id);
  }
```

Is this the perfect solution :

```
 public CITY Find(int comId1, int comId2)
        {
            return context.CITies.Where(c => c.CITY_ID == comId1 && c.COUNTRY_ID == comId2).SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

---

I try to implement the following methods in my interface :

```
T Find(int id);
T Find(int comId1,int comId2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method support multiples parameters, the only is you need to make sure to pass your keys in the correct order:

```
context.CITies.Find(comId1, comId2);
```

When you have composite keys, Entity Framework requires you to define an order of the key properties. You can do this using the [`Column`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Composite) annotation to specify an order. You can also do the same using Fluent Api configuring your keys like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cities>().HasKey(t => new { t.Id1, t.Id2 });
```

If you want a `Find` generic method that works for all your entity types, you could do this:

```
public T Find<T>(params object[] keyValues) where T: class
{ 
  return context.Set<T>().Find(keyValues);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by the correct order please ?

Comment: Say i have composite key `id:int` , `fromdate:datetime` what's the order does the `Find` method depend on ?

Comment: right now i use `edmx` did u mean the `order` of the column in the `xml`

Comment: I haven't worked with a edmx a long time ago, but as far I know if you are using EF 6, your edmx should generate Fluent Api configurations. Check in the generated code if you find a fluent api configuration like a show in my answer.

Comment: Please Could you help me :
according to your recommendation i put `T Find<T>(params object[] keyValues) ;` instead of `T Find(int id);` but i'm little confused how to implement it in my class

Comment: You should not use a generic method if you are not going to create a generic class for all your entities like [generic repository](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte) pattern. You should declare it as you intended to do before but passing an array of objects as parameters

Comment: Really thanks a lot i change it to `T Find(params object[] keyValues) ;`